# Techniques to Identify Root Cause of winspool!EnumPorts Incorrectly Returning 0 Ports

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, winapi, apimonitor

Have a Windows environment where the "Ports" tab is empty on all network printers, but only on some win7 clients. All other printing functionality from these clients works to printers on those print servers. Due to the way the environment is set up I cannot easily attach a kernel debugger to these vSphere virtual machines.

- Server 2008 R2 machines - OK
- Clean Win7 machine - OK
- Win7 machine + much 3rd party software, including 3rd party device drivers, multiple API hooking software, etc - BROKEN

All machines are joined to same domain, and logged in as same user.
Using [Rohitab API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) on Explorer.exe I identified the winspool [EnumPorts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162687(v=vs.85).aspx) is succeeding, but returning 0 ports on the failing machine, but under same user account/same network and same parameters it returns 600+ ports on both working machines..

I wrote a test C++ program to test EnumPorts on its own. The Visual Studio 2015 project + binary is [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiFhB4fT6aiTkTIlppvmFr4qTAQO)

The key part of this program is:

```
pPortInfo = (PORT_INFO_2 *)malloc(cbNeeded);
            bResult = EnumPorts(argv[1],
                2,
                (LPBYTE)pPortInfo,
                cbNeeded,
                &cbNeeded,
                &cbReturned);
```

On a working machine output from pPortInfo is :

```
CALL: EnumPorts("\\PRINTSERVER01",(LPBYTE)pPortInfo,4096,&cbNeeded,&cbReturned)
RETURNED: false ERROR CODE: 122 ERROR MSG: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
CALL: EnumPorts("\\PRINTSERVER01",(LPBYTE)pPortInfo,121800,&cbNeeded,&cbReturned)
RETURNED: true ERROR CODE: 0 ERROR MSG: The operation completed successfully.
cbReturned = 629
PORT #0
Port Name: TS005
Monitor Name: Dynamic Print Monitor
Description: Inactive TS Port
Port Type: WRITE READ 
PORT #1
Port Name: TS004
Monitor Name: Dynamic Print Monitor
Description: Inactive TS Port
Port Type: WRITE READ 
etc...
```

On the broken machine:

```
CALL: EnumPorts("\\PRINTSERVER01",(LPBYTE)pPortInfo,4096,&cbNeeded,&cbReturned)
RETURNED: true ERROR CODE: 0 ERROR MSG: The operation completed successfully.
cbReturned = 0
```

What I have identified/tried so far

- Using [SysInternals AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to compare machines there are hundreds of differences between Windows Services Configuration/Drivers/Hooking DLLs on both machines. I want to find a technique to narrow this down to potential culprit without having to remove/disable all these items
- I've tried disabling all hooking DLLs by renaming [AppInit_DLLs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/197571) key and confirming these DLLs no longer load in the process, but it remains broken
- Captured [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) trace - On the working machine network traffic is sent/received to the print server when EnumPorts is called. On the broken machine there is no network traffic sent to the print server at all. However on the broken machine you can still run commands like net view /all \ and map to printers/drives on the remote print server.
- Used [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44226) RPC trace, this logs the RPC calls but not sure how to interpret this data. None of the calls appear to be failing.
- Looking deeper into winspool!EnumPorts it uses [NdrClientCall2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374215(v=vs.85).aspx) to communicate with print server but these calls are not failing.
- Tried disabling local firewall
- Tried netsh winsock reset and restarting
- Tested with antivirus disabled
- Created a filter in Windows Event viewer to look at ALL windows event log entries during the time test is run and can't find any seemingly related errors
- Running my test tool via WinDbg there are no first chance exceptions or other errors
- Tried setting a breakpoint at the completion of EnumPort function then created a complete memory dmp with [NotMyFault](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip) but couldn't find anything, and didn't really know what I was looking for in the first place
- Used [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to look for missing registry keys/files and couldn't find any

Comment: I don't get it, if you see the Ports tab empty then why on Earth would you expect your program to find any?  Add a port and see what hits the fan.  And ask for help at superuser.com.

Comment: Because debugging explorer has loads of other stuff going on at the same time, there are 1000s of calls to winspool functions. I wrote the test program in the hope to make it easier to debug, with only 1 call to winspool, and so RPC tracing/network tracing can filter just on this process. I am interested in how to further debug why the EnumPorts function call is not working, I don't think super user is the right crowd.

Comment: you need attach debugger to spoolsv.exe and set breakpoint to spoolsv.PrvEnumPortsW function - when you call EnumPorts in self process - internally this function called.

Comment: Thanks this got my closer .. spoolsv.exe calls GetAddrInfoW("<print server") which fails with 11001 = No such host is known and DnsQuery_W ( "<print server>") which returns 9701 - DNS record does not exist. But dns resolves correctly on same machine using nslookup <print server>

Comment: in this case can attach debugger to "svchost.exe -k NetworkService" where dnsrslvr.dll live and set breakpoint to dnsrslvr.R_ResolverQuery which internal call dnsapi.Query_Main and try looking what here going..

Comment: usual next fuctions called from dnsapi.dll: Query_Main -> Query_Start -> Query_Wire -> Send_AndRecv -> Send_AndRecvUdpWithParam -> sendUdpToNextDnsServers -> sendUsingServerInfo -> sendto..

Comment: This led me to the solution. Issue was caused by 3rd party DLL C:\Program Files\Citrix\Universal Print Client\UpProv.dll